# What do the symbols in the April 13, 2022 xkcd comic actually mean?

Tags: notation, recreational-mathematics

[This xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/2606/) contains a list of mathematical symbols present in Unicode along with humorous interpretations of what they mean based on their shape. While I recognize a couple of them (disjoint union, power set, is defined as), most of them are symbols I haven’t encountered before.

What do these symbols mean? I’ve tried looking some of them up but the Google search results I’m seeing are largely about the Unicode characters themselves rather than for how they’re used in mathematics.

(Bonus: the caption for the image references U+2A0B, a symbol that’s a superimposed $\sum$ and $\int$ symbol. I’ve never seen this before and am very curious what it means.)

| Codepoint | Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U+29CD | ⧍ | Shark |
| U+23E7 | ⏧ | Traffic Circle |
| U+2A33 | ⨳ | *Hashtag* |
| U+2A7c | ⩼ | Confused Alligator |
| U+299E | ⦞ | Snack |
| U+2A04 | ⨄ | Drink Refill |
| U+2B48 | ⭈ | Snakes over there |
| U+225D | ≝ | Definitely, for sure |
| U+237C | ⍼ | Larry Potter |
| U+2A50 | ⩐ | Spider caught with a cup and index card |
| U+2A69 | ⩩ | ℍℍ |
| U+2368 | ⍨ | :/ |
| U+2118 | ℘ | Snake |
| U+2AC1 | ⫁ | User experience [sideways] |
| U+232D | ⌭ | Rolling dough between your hands to shape it into a ball |
| U+2A13 | ⨓ | Integral that avoids a bee on the whiteboard |
| U+2A0B | ⨋ | Mathematicians need to calm down |

[image: U+2A0B ⨋ Mathematicians need to calm down]

Comment: def = is "defined to be equal", similar to "assigned equals" $:=$

Comment: See [List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject).

Comment: You're looking at a fancy rho, or p, for another of them

Comment: A lot of these symbols are very nonstandard notation. If these symbols are used in mathematical literature, they will likely be defined by the author.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I checked that list earlier and IIRC most of the symbols from the comic don’t appear there. But it is a great list!

Comment: See also [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://math.uoregon.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/compsymb-1qyb3zd.pdf).

Comment: What you peobably call power set ([U+2118](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2118)) is in fact the [Weierstrass p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function) and specifically denotes a certain elliptic function. I am always terrified when people abuse it to mean power set ...

Comment: In physics, the superimposed sum and integral comes up in quantum mechanics, when you expand a general state (member of a Hilbert space) in terms of basis states. In quantum mechanics, there are cases with discrete and continuous bases. Usually (at least at physics level of rigor), the arguments for the discrete and continuous cases are the same up to replacing an integral over a continuous parameter to a sum over a discrete parameter. So often people do the expansion using the "sum or integral" symbol instead of writing out two copies of the same argument in slightly different notation.

Comment: [ExplainXKCD](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2606) lists all the symbols but not all of them have been fully explained yet.

Comment: I'm speculating, but the xkcd may have been inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424967/what-is-⍼-used-for)

Comment: Apparently there's a [whole lore](https://ionathan.ch/2022/04/09/angzarr.html) for that question.

Comment: This question is not about mathematics.  We have been presented with a collection of glyphs which appear in a particular font standard, and asked to identify them.  This is more appropriately posed to experts on those standards, e.g. the [tex.se] community.